# Finding the lowest average Hamming distance when the order of the strings matter

Tags: algorithms

I have a sequence of binary strings that I want to find a match for among a set of longer sequences of binary strings. A match means that the compared sequence gives the lowest average Hamming distance when all elements in the shorter sequence have been matched against a sequence in one of the longer sets.

Let me try to explain with an example. I have a set of video frames that have been hashed using a perceptual hashing algorithm so that the video frames that look the same has roughly the same hash. I want to match a short video clip against a set of longer videos, to see if the clip is contained in one of these. This means that I need to find out where the sequence of the hashed frames in the short video has the lowest average Hamming distance when compared with the long videos.

The short video is the sub strings Sub1, Sub2 and Sub3, and I want to match them against the hashes of the long videos in Src. The clue here is that the strings need to match in the specific order that they are given in, e.g. that Sub1 always has to match the element before Sub2, and Sub2 always has to match the element before Sub3. In this example it would map thusly: Sub1-Src3, Sub2-Src4 and Sub3-Src5.

So the question is this: **is there an algorithm for finding the lowest average Hamming distance when the order of the elements compared matter?** The naïve approach to compare the substring sequence to every source string won't cut it of course, so I need something that preferably can match a (much) shorter sub string to a set of million of elements. I have looked at MVP-trees, BK-trees and similar, but everything seems to only take into account one binary string and not a sequence of them.

```
Sub1: 100111011111011101
Sub2: 110111000010010100
Sub3: 111111010110101101

Src1: 001011010001010110
Src2: 010111101000111001
Src3: 101111001110011101
Src4: 010111100011010101
Src5: 001111010110111101
Src6: 101011111111010101
```

I have added a calculation of the examples below. (The Hamming distances aren't correct, but it doesn't matter)

```
**Run 1.**
dist(Sub1, Src1) = 8
dist(Sub2, Src2) = 10
dist(Sub3, Src3) = 12
average = 10

**Run 2.**
dist(Sub1, Src2) = 10
dist(Sub2, Src3) = 12
dist(Sub3, Src4) = 10
average = 11

**Run 3.**
dist(Sub1, Src3) = 7
dist(Sub2, Src4) = 6
dist(Sub3, Src5) = 10
average = 8

**Run 4.**
dist(Sub1, Src3) = 10
dist(Sub2, Src4) = 4
dist(Sub3, Src5) = 2
average = 5
```

So the winner here is sequence 4 with an average distance of 5.

Comment: You're probably looking for something more like Levenshtein distance, which *does* take this order into account.  In any case, because you're dealing with a million elements, you're probably going to have to specify your problem with a little more detail than this.  Try to provide us with some sample input and output, and there might be a chance we can formulate an algorithm.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The input would be what I posted in my example, only with longer bit strings and a lot more of them.

Comment: And what would the output look like?

Comment: It would be an int describing the average distance between them.
E.g. ( dist(Sub1, Src3) + dist(Sub2, Src4) + dist(Sub3, Src5) ) / 3 = 4

Comment: Make the calculations for your input data above to create sample output data, and put that in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have done the calculations now.

Comment: You say that the example answers you provided don't correspond to hamming distance.  What do they correspond to?  Can you provide the actual method you used to arrive at the numbers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, they are "pseudo-calculations" if you will. I haven't got the possibility to run the source code at the moment, so I just did an example output and picked the Hamming distances from my head at random, instead of computing the actual distances using the examples strings above. It's just to illustrate that I get a Hamming distance back, and I do an average of it.

Comment: Well, the whole purpose of asking for sample output data was to 1.  give us a basis for creating an algorithm and 2. get you to think about the process.  If you can't provide that, then tell us about the use case.  What is this for, and why do you need it?

Comment: Do you have any other information that might be exploitable? Are there commonalities between the substrings or the source strings - or are they truly undetermined?

Comment: @Frank The commonalities is that there is a set of video frames that I have hashed using a perceptual hashing algorithm, and I try to match them to a set of source videos that has also been hashed. I.e. I am trying to find out where a video clip belongs in a longer video using perceptual hashing algorithms. The compared sequence that gives the lowest average Hamming distance is usually where the video clip belongs in the source video.

Comment: Does that mean that the hamming distance of the first substring will be smallest at the position, where the video is located, such that you could greedily search for the minimum hamming distances, one after the other with subsequently shorter amounts of strings to check against?

Comment: @Frank Yes, in theory it will be, but slight mismatches between the frames might give slight variations in Hamming distances, meaning that checking for just one frame won't always give a reliable result. E.g. I can get the best match for frame 1 (in the wrong source video), but frame 2, 3, and so forth will match poorly since it was matched in the wrong video. But when the average is low, then I have usually found a good match for most frames.

Comment: Can you give an order of magnitude how many subs and srcs are to be considered in a typical run of this algorithm?

Comment: @TheMorph One full length (1.5 hours) film (source) is about 5000 frames. A clip (sub) can be anything between 1 and 5000 (or longer) frames. I don't have an upper bound on how many source films I am going to index, just as many as possible.

Comment: May one only match contiguous values of src? Or can one match for example like this: sub1 matches src1, sub2 matches src3 and sub3 matches sub4?

Comment: @TheMorph It should be continually since the frames appear after each other, with no skipping or "extra" frames having been inserted anywhere that need to be accounted for.

Comment: May I ask you to comment on my suggestions so we get to know more about the specifics of your problem?

Comment: @TheMorph I have updated the main question with more specifics, but I will comment your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could just concatenate your srcs and subs respectively. After that you can use a [sequence allignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) algorithm of your taste, like the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) or the more general [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm).

Comment: Second answer as it states a completely different approach that emerged after further clarification of the question.

Comment: I am unsure if this could work since this algorithm appears to find matches where there are "gaps" i.e. missing frames (bit strings) in my case.

Comment: That is right, it matches even with gaps, but it will return a value of how good the matching is. You could work with a threshold. Maybe the more general Needleman–Wunsch algorithm is a better fit for your case. You should be able to define a big negative value for gaps inside the string but only a small or null negative value for missing parts at the beginning and end.

Comment: I think that Needleman-Wunsch might work, so I am awarding you the bounty. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any algorithm specific for this problem, but this seems like an optimization problem.

I would suggest [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) as a starting point. Combined with a depth-first search to get upper bounds (your lowest hamming distance) for the bounding and you won't need to traverse all edges of the tree. If your accumulated hamming distance on a node is already bigger than the lowest already found from root to a leaf you can stop traversing subtrees of this node.

If you can find a good [heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_%28computer_science%29) to chose what branch to visit next you may further reduce the number of paths to traverse. Something like expand subtrees with lowest accumulated hamming distance yet.

Another thing you could maybe incorporate in the heuristic is the distance to the end. The further you are away from the end of the video the bigger the chance to find a better match thus lower hamming distance. (If I understood your problem correctly)

If you use heuristics with some crossover of depth-first and breadth-first seach, but may be even faster (I didn't made the math yet). The idea would be to traverse strictly from root to leaf but after you are done you decide which subtree you want to expand next from root to tree, not only looking on all the nodes you discovered by the last traversal (in contrast to recursive depth-first search). Thus you *may* find lower bounds even sooner, but you will need more space for computation as you will most likely have more nodes in the list of unexplored ones and you can summarize the results for subtrees later.

Comment: May be not suitable as I assumed the matchings wouldn't need to be contagious. Thus it may work not the way the asker intended.